# OpenGL ES1, imported blender texture not resizing in oolong/iphone

Tags: opengl-es, textures, blender, oolong-engine

just had a simple question about opengl es that I couldn't find the answer to. So I am trying to display simple meshes made in blender using oolong3D's blenderparse example, but when I import the textures from blender they always stay the same size. What I mean is that in blender I can resize the texture to fit the mesh, but when I import them in opengl the size stays the same and they don't fit the whole mesh. Here is a link to some pics and some code used to apply the textures: http://img17.imageshack.us/g/blenderview.png/. Is there some missing code that I need to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the mesh in edit mode (to go to `edit mode`, select the mesh and press `tab`).